# Where did the word 'Greece' come from?

Tags: etymology

The Greeks I've met say something that to my ears sounds like *'Elatha'*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you are hearing is most likely the correct Greek pronunciation of Elláda (Ελλάδα). This is the modern Greek word for the name of their country, ultimately derived from the Ancient Greek Hellás (Ἑλλάς).

The English name for the country, "Greece", derives from the Latin name "Graecia". Wiktionary gives a fairly full etymology:

> From Latin Graecia < Ancient Greek Γραικός (Graikos), a character in Greek mythology, the son of Thessalos, the king of Fthia, from whom Ἑλλάς (Hellas, “Greece”) and Ἕλληνες (Hellenes, “the Greeks”) got their names.

Although this entry explains the etymology of the name "Greece", it is admittedly slightly confusing about the etymology of "Hellas". [This page](http://www.allwords.com/word-Hellas.html) gives a hypothetical etymology:

> Etymology: From Ancient Greek  (Hellas
>   "Greece"), from prefix - (el-ελ "sun,
>   bright, shiny", (elios, "sun")) + 
>   (las-λας "rock, stone"). : "The land of
>   the sun and the rock".

I would not however want to comment on the veracity of this source. All that is known for sure is that Hellas originally referred to a small area within Ancient Greece and only later came to refer to all Greece. [This Yahoo answer](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080620094823AAjGdYu) gives some handy details.

Comment: @cindi: Indeed, I'll edit that in. It's a mistake in the original Wiktionary entry.

Comment: Also, answer is updated now.

Comment: as an additional point of reference, "hellenistic" was used in the early centuries AD to describe Jews who were either a) not living in Palestine, or b) not born in Palestine (perhaps as proselytes, or just that their families had been moved prior to their birth).

Comment: @warren - It wasn't that they were not living in Palestine; it was that they were living among non-Jewish communities (most notably in Alexandria, in Ptolemaic Egypt) and were assimilating into the surrounding Hellenistic culture - shaving, dressing in Greek fashions, attending the gymnasium, etc.

Comment: Exactly, @MT_Head is right. Nothing special about the Jews here, just the Greeks (and their associated culture).

Comment: @cindi: For what it's worth, in Arabic, Hindi and some other languages Greece is called *Yoonaan* (and some other languages have different but related names); apparently this comes from *Ionia*. And according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_of_Greece), the *Hellas* name is used in Norwegian and Chinese.

Comment: According to all the Greek mythology references I can find with Google, the sons of Thessalos were Antiphos and Pheidippos. Was *Thessalos, king of Fthia* a different Thessalos, or were the contributors to Wiktionary who wrote this just wrong?  [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=greek) has a completely different etymology for *Graikhos*.

Comment: The AllWords etymology for _Hellas_ is almost certainly **not** true. It would require an awful lot of tinkering and reworking to get the words for ‘sun’ and ‘stone’ to fit into what we have in Ἑλλάς. The ‘sun’ word is usually borrowed as _helio-_, but its Homeric form is ἡέλιο- _hēélio-_ and in Cretan it’s ἁβέλιο- _habélio-_ (both from Proto-Greek _*hāwéli̯o-_, from PIE _*seh₂-u̯él-i̯o-_, derived from _*séh₂-u̯ōl_ ‘sun’, which also gives Latin _sōl_), and there is no sane way to get _*hel-_ from _*hāwel-_ in (Proto-)Greek. The ‘stone’ word is not λας _las_ as they write, but λᾶας _lā.as_, →

Comment: → in two syllables (the first of which is long). Considering that Ἑλλάς also has its stress on the _-la-_ syllable, it’s very unlikely that the second syllable in λᾶας would have been syncopated away—and what’s more is that the final syllable in Ἑλλάς is **short**. So for Ἑλλάς to derive from ‘sun + stone’, we’d need no less than two instances of _*V̄₁V̆₂_ (= long vowel of quality A followed by short vowel of quality B) becoming _*V̆₂_ (= short vowel of quality B): _*ā(w)ĕ_ → _*e_, and _*āă_ → _*ă_. Such a development would be utterly unparallelled in Greek and can safely be ruled out.

Answer (score 4):

Greece, as the name of a country, was more used by outsiders than Greeks, at least in the Hellenistic period. Most of them would think of themselves as Athenians or Corinthians, and Hellas was **not** the place where they lived, but the area where people spoke Greek as opposed to barbarian languages; similar to mediaeval *Christendom*.  (The Greek colonies in Italy were referred to as 'Megale Hellas' or Greater Greece).
It was only when Greece became part of the Roman Empire that a name was needed for the geographical area, and unsurprisingly the Roman word Graecia was used.
It appears that Germany had a similar history:  [Why does Germany's English name differ from its German name?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/7785/8019)