# Why does Germany's English name differ from its German name?

Tags: etymology, proper-nouns

Germany in German is Deutschland and the language is Deutsch.  I'm used to words being anglicized, but why is there a complete replacement in this case?

Comment: As a note, this is not at all a unique case with the name of Germany in English. French and German names for other countries often differ greatly from their native names.

Comment: @Noldorin: But it is not very common to call a neigbouring Western-European country by a name derived from an entirely different IE root.

Comment: Tim Osterholm on his Table of Nations website brought forth an interesting theory that the word German originated long ago from the ancient Assyrian city of Kerman. The word Deutsh is also linked with Assyria. It seems that during the fall of Ninevah, this group of people migrated north to escape from the invading Babylonians (and Scythians too perhaps). Coming from a civilized area to the more primitive tribes of ancient Germany perhaps gave them an influence there out of proportion to their numbers.

Comment: Related question on [history.se]: [Why are Germans referred to so differently in different languages?](http://history.stackexchange.com/q/29028/1546)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Germany did not officially unite as a singular country until [1871](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_of_Germany).  Before that, there were a number of different regions like Bavaria, Prussia, the Hanseatic League, Saxony, and so on.  There was also a long period of time when this region was part of the Holy Roman Empire.  Before this, the peoples that eventually became Germany were grouped into various tribes.

Because of the lack of a single unifying name or country, the Germans ended up being named various things in different regions.

Here is a [list of the names for Germans/Germany, grouped together by their origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_for_Germany).  In summary:

1. From the Old High German *diutisc* meaning "of the people" (e.g. *Deutschland*).
2. From Latin *Germania*, probably meaning "neighbor" (e.g. *Germany*).
3. From the name of the Alemanni tribe (e.g. *Allemagne*).
4. From the name of the Saxon tribe (e.g. *Saksa*).
5. From the Protoslavic word *němьcь*, meaning "foreigner", literally "unable to speak" (e.g. *Německo*).
6. From the Germanic word *Volk*, meaning "folk" or "people" (e.g. *Vokietija*).

Comment: Note that the Latin Germania from which Germany is derived probably had its origin ultimately as a Celtic loanward. (For example, how the Gauls would refer to the Germans/non-Celtic tribes.) Also, Germany certainly *did* exist as a concept (if not a country) before the 19th century - the King of Germany was a title the Holy Roman Empire (also called the German Empire) held.

Comment: @Noldorin: I didn't mean to suggest that there was no connection between any of the sub-parts of present-day Germany, but the connections were much looser, and it wasn't really an official country until that 1871 unification.  I still think that what I describe is a key contributor to the number of completely different names for Germany.

Comment: @Noldorin: Interesting, I had no idea idea that "Germania" came from Celtic. I suppose the Celts met the Germans before the Romans did, having spread all over Europe much earlier.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Your theory has merit. An older, single state is more likely to get a stable name. I suppose the same could be said about the decentralized Netherlands/Low Countries/Holland/The Dutch. As for Spain, one might conjecture that 500 years of unity were enough. But what about Italy? Could it be that the ancient memory of Roman Italy - the last time it ever was a unity - was enough to give it a name much more stable than that of Germany? That is somewhat doubtful, though it is not impossible.

Comment: @Cerberus: Good question about Italy, and I don't know nearly as much about it.  Maybe the peninsula was known as the Italian Peninsula even during the centuries while there was no country of Italy as such?  And/or, maybe the broad influence of Latin played some role?

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Italy has simply always been known as Italia etc. all through the Middle Ages, as far as I know, even after several foreign invasions - some of which by Germanic tribes such as the Lombards, who permanently settled in large regions in the northern half of Italy in the early Middle Ages. Even so, the name Germania, too, was in wide use during the Middle Ages; it is difficult to say why no different names for Italy or the Italians were adopted by foreigners. "Romans" would have been a good candidate, "Tuscans" and "Latins" mediocre ones.

Comment: @Cerberus: Yeah, Roman contact with Celts goes back a long way (they were in Northern Italy in antiquity). It's a curious history; the linguistic groups of Celtic and Italic (and thus probably the peoples) are more closely related to each other than either is to Germanic. However, Romans didn't differentiate between the two (they were all barbarians) before about the 3rd/2nd century BC.

Comment: And yes, Italy had had a constant name throughout history thanks to the Roman hegemony over Europe in antiquity (even over the parts of Germania and Scythia it did not conquer). The name "Italia" has truly ancient origins ("land of the bull god" if my memory serves me) - it was without doubt the 2nd country in Europe. In fact, the Romans even spread their own name for Greece (Graecia) in favour of Hellas.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Oh absolutely, Germany was never truly a country until then (unlike many of its neighbours), despite close ties. I always liked Voltaire's quote: "This agglomeration which was called and which still calls itself the Holy Roman Empire was neither holy, nor Roman, nor an empire." Not only witty, but largely true!

Comment: Brilliant answer.

Answer (score 12):

Wikipedia has a [huge article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_Germany) on the subject. The two passages most related to your question are:

> The name *Deutschland* and the other similar-sounding names above are derived from the Old High German *diutisc*, or similar variants from Proto-Germanic *Þeudiskaz, which originally meant "of the people". This in turn comes from a Germanic word meaning "folk" (leading to Old High German *diot*, Middle High German *diet*), and was used to differentiate between the speakers of Germanic languages and those who spoke Celtic or Romance languages. These words come from *teuta, the Proto-Indo-European word for "people" (Lithuanian *tauto*, Old Irish *tuath*, Old English *þeod*).

And:

> The name *Germany* and the other similar-sounding names above are derived from the Latin *Germania*, of the 3rd century BC, a word of uncertain origin. The name appears to be a Gaulish term, and there is no evidence that it was ever used by the Germanic tribes themselves. Julius Caesar was the first to use *Germanus* in writing when describing tribes in north-eastern Gaul in his *Commentarii de Bello Gallico*; he records that four northern Belgic tribes, namely, the Condrusi, Eburones, Caeraesi and Paemani, were collectively known as Germani. In 98, Tacitus wrote *Germania* (the Latin title was actually: *De Origine et situ Germanorum*), an ethnographic work on the diverse set of Germanic tribes outside the Roman Empire. Unlike Caesar, Tacitus claims that the name *Germani* was first applied to the Tungri tribe.

It should be noted that English does have the word *Dutch*, coming from the same source as *Deutsch*. It's just that nowadays it refers to, well, Dutch, rather than German. See [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=dutch&searchmode=none) for further details:

> *Dutch* late 14c., used first of Germans generally, after c.1600 of Hollanders, from M.Du. *duutsch*, from O.H.G. *duit-isc*, corresponding to O.E. *þeodisc* "belonging to the people," used especially of the common language of Germanic people, from *þeod* "people, race, nation," from P.Gmc. *theudo "popular, national" (see *Teutonic*), from PIE base *teuta- "people" (cf. O.Ir. *tuoth* "people," O.Lith. *tauta* "people," O.Prus. *tauto* "country," Oscan *touto* "community").
>
> As a language name, first recorded as L. *theodice*, 786 C.E. in correspondence between Charlemagne's court and the Pope, in reference to a synodical conference in Mercia; thus it refers to Old English. First reference to the German language (as opposed to a Germanic one) is two years later. The sense was extended from the language to the people who spoke it (in German, Diutisklant, ancestor of Deutschland, was in use by 13c.).
>
> Sense narrowed to "of the Netherlands" in 17c., after they became a united, independent state and the focus of English attention and rivalry. In Holland, *duitsch* is used of the people of Germany. The M.E. sense survives in Pennsylvania Dutch, who immigrated from the Rhineland and Switzerland.

Comment: Good quotes. Note that "Duitsch" is written with a capital, and that its modern spelling is "Duits", though the old form is still occasionally used by some.

Answer (score 2):

The names for Germany in different languages are quite varied.  English: Germany.  Dutch: Duitsland.  Polish: Niemcy.  Spanish: Alemania.  Wikipedia has a nice explanation of where these different names come from:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_Germany

Answer (score 1):

I'd back up.  Why would you think that the name would be the same?   These are different languages.  The names of numbers, of trees, of colors, etc., differ by language.  So it is not surprising that the names of countries differ.

Comment: Improper nouns, sure. But proper names are usually fairly stable. If you went to Germany, would you expect them to translate "Rob" into their native language, and call you "Rauben"? :)

Comment: Lots of proper names of people are translated. Christopher Columbus is one good example.

Comment: But it usually gets translated to something obviously similar like "Christophe Colomb" or "Cristóbal Colón" or "Kristophara Kolambasa".

Comment: @Dan: There's a certain amount of irony when you call the original name a translation, and assume one of the translations in original.

Comment: Terms (describing whatever) aren't *changed* very much and just adjusted to another language in the process of *assimilating* them.  If the other people speaking this other language already have a term for something, they have no need to assimilate the foreign one.  Germany is located in the middle of a lot of other relevant countries and their languages.  The dozen or so peoples surrounding Germany developed their own names for the Germans, from their point of view.  Ireland, as a counter example, did not have so many different views on it, and thus not so many different names to suffer.